# How to download Ubuntu One App on Samsung Note II?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I am not able to download Ubuntu One App on Samsung Note II - neither via App Store nor via Bar Code. Could the app be made to appear on the screen of the device?

Answer (score 1):

The Bar Code will most likely link you to the Google Play market. A quick google search yielded [this download link](http://www.mediafire.com/?8cmgjf30j2jg5j7) (not verified). Make sure you can install apps off market by clicking on the binary installer (`apk` file) after downloading.

It's better if you can install it from the market because you'd get automatic updates, but if it ain't broke, no need to fix it, right? At least Android gives you the option to install apps off market. If it's not enabled, when you try to install an APK binary, the prompt will take you to the settings where you can toggle this.

Comment: I got through to the point that Google Play confirms it is installed; yet my device says it is NOT installed. also I wasn't asked whether to allow automatic updating so I guess the function is somehow broken within Google Play Market

Comment: I think I found the mistake.  when I go to Market on my computer it allows to send the app to my mobile device.  it then displays the number of my old device Samsung S5660 instead of my new Note II.  this message is in dutch so locally made; it allows a choice of providers, not of devices!

Comment: I found I could switch to the new device, though it was mentioned under the wrong provider.  it has downloaded now.